# Angular implement Observable<any> as synchronous string[] array

Tags: angular, observable, behaviorsubject, ng2-charts

I am trying to grab info saved to firebase and use it dynamically to populate an array for ng2-chart.

The problem I currently have is that the observable does not allow me to populate this array.

```
getEntries(id) {
this.entries2 = this.dataService.getEntries(id);

let datesarr: string[] = [];
let arr = [];
this.dataService.getEntries(id).subscribe((entry) => {
  entry.forEach(function (x) {
    arr.push(x);
  });

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
    //  console.log(arr[i].Q1);
    let x: string = arr[i].Q1;

    // console.log(x);
    datesarr.push(x);

    //this.barChartLabels.push(x); 
//Whenever I try to push this value it encounters an error. 
  }
});
}
```

Am I mis-using the subscribe function for this observable? If so, how can I fix it?

Previously I attempted to use the following snippet:

```
getEntries(id) {
this.entries2 = this.dataService.getEntries(id);
let arr = [];
let datesarr: string[] = [];

this.entries2.forEach(function (entry) {
  entry.forEach(function (x) {
    arr.push(x);
  });
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
    
    let x: string = arr[i].Q1;
    
    datesarr.push(x);
    //this.barChartLabels.push(x);
  }
});
```

I believe the issue is that this observable is async and the barchartlabels line pushes "undefined" instead of any real data.

entries2 is defined as:

```
   entries2: Observable<any>;
```

barchartlabels is just an empty array I am trying to push data to:

```
public barChartLabels: Label[] = [];
```

And the code for grabbing the info from the db in dataService is:

```
  getEntries(id){
   return  this.db.collection(`users/${id}/entries`).valueChanges();
  }
```

Could someone please point me in the right direction as to how to tackle this problem?

Note: I've tried looking into Subjects, but am not sure if they fit into my code as returning the last value of a stream doesn't seem to be all too useful.

Comment: Can you specify the error you get ?

Comment: I am guessing a type problem, barChartLabels expects a Label array. Try to make a cast to Label  => let pushed: Label = x as Label; this.barChartLabels.push(pushed);

Comment: Yup that was it, it was a type error. 
Side note, am I using subscribe correctly? I am still very new to observables and angular.

Comment: Yes its correct : though I would be careful with memory leak You should have an attribute private sub: Subscription. Then you affect it like so : this.sub = this.dataService.getEntries(id).subscribe(.... And you unsubscribe it in ngOnDestroy : if (this.sub) { this.sub.unsubscribe() }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be a Type problem. this.barChartLabels expects an Array of Label as you pointed

```js
this.barChartLabels: Label[] = [];
```

So you just try to cast the x data to Label:

```js
getEntries(id) {
this.entries2 = this.dataService.getEntries(id);

let datesarr: string[] = [];
let arr = [];
this.dataService.getEntries(id).subscribe((entry) => {
  entry.forEach(function (x) {
    arr.push(x);
  });

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
    //  console.log(arr[i].Q1);
    let x: string = arr[i].Q1;

    // console.log(x);
    datesarr.push(x);

    this.barChartLabels.push(x as Label); // note as Label 

  }
});
}
```

Comment: Oh my god, thank you!

Comment: Ok It was just my 1st guess : a type problem. I am editing the answer to be more clear

Comment: also you can add syntax coloring with '''typescript <CODE HERE> ''' (use the tick ` instead of the quote'